# How do I apply a border on a picture from another picture

Tags: png, images, jpg

I want to add the border on this picture:

[image: http://aurorasvoice.org/uploads/quotes/martin-luther-king-jr.jpg]

to this picture:

[image: http://aurorasvoice.org/uploads/quotes/daniel_webster.png]

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: i dont see why this question was marked negatively.

Comment: Far from enough info in this Q.

Comment: The only thing we need to know is: "is the border a layer style?"

Comment: what other information do you need? i want to apply the border in the martin luther king photo on the daniel webster photo? i dont know what a layer style is.

Comment: You're prob being down voted because the answer is so elementary. It required more effort to come to this site and ask, than it would have to "Google it". "Create a border in Photoshop" returns 15.8 Million results.

Comment: Ok jonathan... doubleclick layer, stroke it with the same color selected with your colorpicker. What more info do you need?

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose the color(to be the border) you want in your color palette.
2. Image -> Canvas Size (increase this by the thickness of the border you want).

or

1. "Select All".
2. Edit -> Stroke -> then set the color, line width, inside.

or

1. Select the layer of the image (if it's multiple layers, select them and create a smart object).
2. Layer -> Layer Style -> Stroke...

Comment: can i do this in paint.net?